# The equivalent definition of denting point

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-analysis

How i can prove that

> If $K$ is a subspace of Banach space $X$, $x$ is denting point of $K$,when for every $\varepsilon>0$,there is a unit vector $x^{*}\in X^{*}$ and $\delta>0$ such that $x\in S(x^{*},\delta)$ and the diam of the slice $S(x^{*},\delta)$ is less of $\varepsilon$.

I only know that we should utilize **Hahn-Banach Theorem**.

Comment: If I get the definition (from your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571567/every-denting-point-and-strongly-exposed-point-is-extreme-point) correctly, then *no* point of a *subspace* should be a denting point. A subspace also has no extreme points.

Comment: If put $M=\overline{con}(K \setminus B_{\epsilon}(x))$, then       by **Hahn-Banach Theorem** there exist $x^{*}\in X^{*}$ such that $x^{*}(x)\neq 0$ and $x^{*}=0$ on M, when $x$ is denting point ($x\notin M$).

Comment: The given definition in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571567/every-denting-point-and-strongly-exposed-point-is-extreme-point is correct. Also there are examples that have denting and extreme points. See Example 8.4 http://www.math.caltech.edu/simon_chp8.pdf. that a compact convex subset $K\subset‎\mathbb{R}^{2}$ has extreme point.

Comment: Sure, there are sub*sets* that have extreme points, but sub*spaces* don't have any.